# 2 Different Outputs When Reversing Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reverse

I am learning Javascript on a book and have to practice reversing an array by creating my own reverse function. **The array must be reversed without creating a new variable to hold the reversed array.** I thought I found a solution, but when I try to output my answer in 2 different ways (see below), I get different outputs:

```
function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    array = array.slice(0, i).concat(array.pop()).concat(array.slice(i));
  }
  console.log(array);
}

var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
```

Here are the outputs:

```
reverseArrayInPlace(array);
console.log(array);
> [ 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ]
> [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
```

When `console.log()` is used within the function, I get my desired answer.

When `console.log()` is used outside the function, I get the original array with the last element missing. **I would like an explanation to this phenomenon.**

Comment: I *re*-upvoted this to counteract the `-1`. Not that I think this is a *great* question, but we are gonna discourage new users like Kevin if we just go around downvoting without providing any explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The `array` in the function is on a different scope than that at the global / window level -- the global `array` is never touched; the function changes a local copy of it instead.

If you didn't pass `array` as a parameter to the function, then it would act on the now unmasked global `array` variable:

```js
function reverseArrayInPlace() { // <-- no parameter
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    array = array.slice(0, i).concat(array.pop()).concat(array.slice(i));
  }
  console.log(array);
}

var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
reverseArrayInPlace();
console.log(array);
```

(...although it is generally bad practice to use globals like that, partly because it's easy to accidentally mask them with local variables just as you did here.   A better pattern would be for functions to receive their data as params and return a value, so you can decide, when you call the function, what to assign that returned value to.)

Answer (score 1):

In the first loop of your `for` you are calling `array.pop()` which modifies the array passed as argument, but then you are creating a new array storing it in the same variable, so the **reference** to the original array is lost, and then in the subsequent loops the modified array is the one being generated inside your function.

Look at this code, I added a line to copy the original array, thus not modificating the original passed as argument.

```js
function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
 array = array.slice(); //copying the passed array to not change the original
 for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
  array = array.slice(0, i).concat(array.pop()).concat(array.slice(i));
 }
 console.log(array);
}

var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

reverseArrayInPlace(array);
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for addressing the issue with the '10' missing from the original array.

So basically, when I create a new reference, let's say `var a = b`, then the expressing in `b` is read first, then assigned to the variable `a`, correct?

Comment: @KevinBie Not sure if I understood correctly, in JS when you store an array (or an object) in a variable, what you are actually doing is storing its memory address in the variable and not the array itself. So if you do `var a = [1, 2];`, `a` internally will be an address pointing to the `[1, 2]` array, then if you do `var b = a;` what you are doing is storing the same address from `a` into `b`, so now `a` and `b` will be pointing to the same location in memory, if you modify the array in `b`, the array in `a` will be changed. Hope this clarifies your issue.

Comment: @KevinBie What you are trying to do is some book/guide exercise? I might be wrong but you can try the built-in `array.reverse()` to flip the array.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `reverseArrayInPlace` you are *reassigning* the `array` variable, not *changing* (mutating) it. The array you pass in, therefore, is not changed. The *inside* console.log sees the *new* `array` while the one *outside* sees the original.

Perhaps you want something like this instead

```
function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    array = array.slice(0, i).concat(array.pop()).concat(array.slice(i));
  }
  return array;
}

var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

var newArray = reverseArrayInPlace(array)

console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: Hello Zach, thanks for your answer! I guess the mutation concept was the primary issue here. I'm glad that you have brought this up! I understand my problem in depth now. 
As for the proposed solution, I do not think it would be appropriate for my case even though it works because the book specifically stated that I change the original array instead of creating a new variable for it.

Answer (score 1):

Just a different approach by using the function stack for storing an item of the array by popping the value, check the length of the array and call the function again with the same object reference and then unshift the temporary stored value.

While working for a small amount of values and because of the limited stack, it is not advisable to use this beside of educational purpose.

```js
function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
    var temp = array.pop();
    if (array.length) {
        reverseArrayInPlace(array);
    }
    array.unshift(temp);
}

var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

reverseArrayInPlace(array);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hello Nina, thanks for providing an alternate and unique solution!

Would it be possible to clarify what the line `array.length && reverseArrayInPlace(array);` does?

I mainly do not understand the purpose of using the && operator in this case.

Comment: it is a [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()), which checks the left side for a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value and if not (a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value) it checks the other side by calling the function. i changed the code to a user friendly `if` statement.